# Отпарсить сайт при помощи PySide как HTML через lxml

Tags: python, qt, парсер, pyside

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from lxml import html
import requests


class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

url = 'http://www.****'
r = Render(url)
tree = r.frame.toHtml()
```

Получаю через PySide страницу (данные тянуться через javascript). Потом хочу ее отпарсить при помощи lxml. Но она не парсится, так как, значение tree строковое. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это просто:

```
from lxml.html import etree
etree.fromstring(html_text)
```

А можно распарсить используя `QtWebKit`. После окончания загрузки у главного фрейма запрашиваете `documentElement`, а у того есть методы поиска, используя `css-селекторы`:

```
doc = self.frame.documentElement()
print(doc.findFirst("#tab-statistics-0-statistic .parts"))
print(doc.findAll('tr'))
```

Comment: Все получилось. И ещё вопрос попутный: как через QtWebKit отрарбатывать click ?

Comment: У `QWebElement` есть метод `evaluateJavaScript` и мне кажется через `javascript` можно сделать, но как именно -- не знаю. Я разве-что похожее делал -- через `javascript` кликал на объект: `doc.findFirst(...).evaluateJavaScript("this.click();")`.
Лучше, как отдельный вопрос задайте -- больше шанса получить ответ.